# Remove Custom Domain/Host from App Service via Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I am unable to find a way to remove a host name from a azure web app/app service.

I have tried to use the following filtering our unwanted hosts, but nothing is removed.

```
Set-AzureWebsite -Name "<<name>>" -HostNames $hosts
```

and

```
Set-AzureRmWebApp -Name "<<name>>" -ResourceGroupName "<<name>>" -HostNames $hosts
```

I have around 200 hosts to delete, however, I can't seem to find an automated way of doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

at a top level this is what you need to do:

1. Get the websites resource
2. Manipulate the hostnames collection
3. Post the changes back to azure

Here is an example of how I did it:

```
$webApp = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "<<Resource-Group-Name>>" -Name "<<App_Name>>"
$webApp.HostNames.Clear()
$webApp.Hostnames.Add($webApp.DefaultHostName)
set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "<<Resource-Group-Name>>" -Name <<App_Name>> -HostNames $webApp.HostNames
```

This will remove all custom hostnames and leave only the default one.

If you want to remove a specific hostname for the collection you could use:

```
$webApp.HostNames.Remove("your_hostname_goes_here")
```

**NOTE**
If your hostname has SSL bindings you will need to remove those first and then delete the hostname.

Answer (score 2):

Just an update
AzureRm has now been replaced with Az so the statement would now be

```
$webApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "<Resource-Group-Name>" -Name "<App-Name>";
$webApp.HostNames.Clear();
$webApp.Hostnames.Add($webApp.DefaultHostName);
Set-AzWebApp `
  -ResourceGroupName "<Resource-Group-Name>" `
  -Name <App-Name> `
  -HostNames $webApp.HostNames;
```

Comment: can you please format your answer? Otherwise, it is a pretty good answer.