# Add a custom domain to a webapp and change it later

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Can I add a custom domain to a webapp and later change it so that the same url is used for a function ?
I mean, initially mount a web service in an app service and later migrate it to azure function and keep the same url of the service.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to Add the custom domain to a web app check [custom domain azure dns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain?tabs=azure-dns)

Once You added the custom domain You Want to Remove the custom domain by using **azure portal** Goto **web app** -> **Custom Domains** -> **App Service Domains** -> Click on the **domain** -> **Delete** it.

Use below `PowerShell` script to Remove all custom domain:

```
$webApp = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "<<Resource-Group-Name>>" -Name "<<App_Name>>"
$webApp.HostNames.Clear()
$webApp.Hostnames.Add($webApp.DefaultHostName)
set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "<<Resource-Group-Name>>" -Name <<App_Name>> -HostNames $webApp.HostNames
```

This will remove all custom hostnames and leave only the default one.

If you want to remove a specific hostname for the collection you could use:

```
$webApp.HostNames.Remove("your_hostname_goes_here")
```

**NOTE** If your hostname has SSL bindings you will need to remove those first and then delete the hostname. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45513832/15997690)

Suppose You don’t want to delete the **Custom domain** and the Default domain name can be used for **other service** you can follow the below steps:

#### **set a default domain**

The domains redirecting to a default domain, follow the below steps.

1. With your static web app opened in the Azure portal, select **Custom domains** in the menu.
2. Select the custom domain you configured as the **Not Set** as **default**.
3. Select as **default**.
4. After the operation completes, refresh the table to confirm that the domains are marked as "default".